# c# Is there a simpler solution for hex2ip

Tags: c#, hex, ip-address

I want convert a hex `C0A8B825` ipV4 to a readable ip address `192.168.184.37`. I am looking for a better solution.

My current solution:

```
var ipAddress = GetIpAddress("C0A8B825"); //192.168.184.37

public static string GetIpAddress(string hex)
{
    var ipPart1 = int.Parse(hex.Substring(0, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    var ipPart2 = int.Parse(hex.Substring(2, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    var ipPart3 = int.Parse(hex.Substring(4, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    var ipPart4 = int.Parse(hex.Substring(6, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    return $"{ipPart1}.{ipPart2}.{ipPart3}.{ipPart4}";
}
```

Comment: `new IPAddress(Convert.ToInt32("C0A8B825", 16)).ToString()`

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen that should be an answer. With some explanation ofc.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen It's worth to be an answer.

Comment: Actually, I just tried it in a fiddle: Results in ArgumentOutOfRangeException. With `Convert.ToInt64` it doesn't throw, but the result is: 37.184.168.192 ... @JeroenvanLangen https://dotnetfiddle.net/kDf8OF

Comment: I found this to be safer: `new IPAddress( (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(Convert.ToInt32("C0A8B825", 16)) : Convert.ToInt32("C0A8B825", 16) )).ToString();`

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen the code not work

Comment: @Fildor A `Convert.ToUInt()` will also work. But the 64 bit will be safer. (IPv6?)

Comment: @live2 I did some assumes... whoops

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Ah, again forgot the IPv6. Would you mind improving your answer? It is really just BigEndian vs. LittleEndian. I don't want to "hijack" ...

Comment: @Fildor I was wrong.. I learned from yours...<3   go ahead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only ever deal with IPv4, you could use:

```
// This will convert to a 32 bit integer representation of the ip
int ip = Convert.ToInt32("C0A8B825", 16);
// IPAddress CTOR needs BigEndian / "Network Byte Order"
if( BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) ip = IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(ip); 
var result = new IPAddress(ip).ToString(); // Will autoformat into the desired string.
```

contents of result:

> 192.168.184.37

I'll see if I can add a Solution for both IPv4 and IPv6 later on.